# How to fail json deserialization when unknown properties with newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json.net

I use an external API that changes unexpectedly. In order to detect these changes, I would like the JSON deserialization (using newtonsoft json.net on ASP.NET Core) to throw an exception whenever it detects a property in the JSON that is not mapped in my POCO.

Is it possible? I tried to use the following deserialization settings but it didn't change anything:

```
            var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                CheckAdditionalContent = true,
            };
```

Comment: @brian-rogers Thsi is not a duplicate (at least not of the question you ponted to). I am asking the opposite question. I want to fail when there are **extra** properties, not **missing** properties.

Comment: It is a duplicate.  Extra properties in the JSON == missing properties in your POCO.  Try the suggested answer.  It does what you want.  Fiddle here if you don't believe me: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ggtYOm

Comment: Oh sorry, you are totally right. Sorry about that.

Comment: @BrianRogers I would say that question is not duplicate. This one is asking to fails on "over-posting", and the other is asking to fail on "under-posting". It just happens that solution is the same because it handles both.

At first I skipped the answer you linked as duplicate because I wanted what OP described. 
Anyway, thanks for great example that shows that `MissingMemberHandling.Error` handle this use case also.

Comment: @MariuszPawelski Re-read both questions more closely.  Both are asking to force an error when the JSON has a property for which the target class does not have a corresponding member. That is what `MissingMemberHandling.Error` does. It does NOT handle the opposite situation, when the JSON lacks a property that the target class has. (Fiddle here if you don't believe me: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MsOJVt). In that case you would want to use `[JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]` attributes. Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/QgjZqE